# Android - textviews are not visible when dynamically created

Tags: java, android, textview

I am trying to make an app that lets the user store and saves contacts. It can save, but it has problems listing.

I have a for loop that runs through the database and prints a set of data for each contact (each row), an image (actually its a string because it passes the path) and a string. It prints them in a scrollview with a linear layout for each contact (each contact has a linear layout of its own, so that i can let one contact occupy a row each). The images come out, however, the textviews are nowhere to be found.

Using log.d(textview.getText()); it confirms that the textviews are created and take up space.
http://chesnutcase.heliohost.org/derpbox/itv1.png
Two "contacts" with names, not printed out. The space inbetween is presumbly by the textview.
http://chesnutcase.heliohost.org/derpbox/itv2.png
Another two "contacts", but without names. The dont have a space between each other. Or at least, a significantly smaller space.
Code:

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    int a = (int) (long) db.countRows();
    LinearLayout theLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.contactsList);
    for(int i = 0;i<a;i++){
        ImageButton image = new ImageButton(this);
        int density=getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp  = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(density,density, 0.5f);
        image.setLayoutParams(vp);
        image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_END);
        int b = a - i;
        try {
            image.setImageBitmap(decodeUri(Uri.parse(db.getContactData("photo_path")[i])));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        theLayout.addView(image);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(db.getContactData("name")[i]);
        Log.d("UserLog","name is "  + db.getContactData("name")[i]);
        Log.d("UserLog","textfield contains " + tv.getText());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp2  = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,0,1f);
        tv.setLayoutParams(vp2);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        theLayout.addView(tv);
    }
```

Any solutions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Double check which orientation you've applied to the `LinearLayout` of your contacts list.

You are setting bad `LayoutParams` to your `TextView`. You're making your `TextView` 0px by 0px with a weight of 1.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp2  = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,0,1f);
tv.setLayoutParams(vp2);
```

Try using one of the `MATCH_PARENT` or `WRAP_CONTENT` constants. They're listed here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT

If you want your `TextView` to take up the remaining width of the screen I would leave the weight as 1, the width as 0, but you need to set the height to a constant like `WRAP_CONTENT`.

You're also setting the size of your `ImageView` to the device screen density (which is a constant) instead of setting a scaling size based off your screen density.

Comment: Thanks, i never realized that i set it to 0px.

The size i wanted for the image just happened to be the screen density's value. Tested on multiple devices.

Comment: how would i go about if i want the textviews to take up the remaining space left behind by the image?

Comment: Do they all happen to be the same screen density? What if your device is MDPI and not HDPI or XHDPI?

Comment: 1 mdpi and another xhdpi

Comment: Edited my answer on how to fill up the remaining space of screen width. You should just have to set the height of the textview to wrap content.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to call **requestLayout();** in order to update the current view layout.

```
theLayout.requestLayout();
```

Also it seems you are creating a view with 0 width and 0 height with that layout params:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp2  = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,0,1f);
```

Comment: well, rotating the screen does update the layout right? and it shouldnt make sense if the image and textview are created at the same function but only one comes out

Comment: I've added something about the layout params.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) for such list. 
You will need to write only one [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews), that's represent logic for creating one row on list.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `CursorAdapter` and a layout xml file, this way you can design it to look exactly how you want, and preview it. It is a lot easier than setting all those fiddly `LayoutParams`

If you have to create them dynamically you may find the text colour is the same as the background, try setting it to something visible like bright red for testing. If you still don't see the text it may be that it's visibility isn't set to `View.VISIBLE` finally the layout may not be the correct size, a handy tip for this is set the background to a suitably eye catching colour, even if there is no text you should see a shaded block.